# Resizing pictures while keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: excel, vba, image

I would like to resize images, keeping the aspect ratio.

```
Public Sub ResizeCab2()

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetShpe As Shape

' Define the sheet that has the pictures
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' Define the range the images is going to fit
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("B3:K24")

' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes

    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

Next targetShape

Call CableOddEven

End Sub
```

The `TargetSheet.Range` means, that the image must be bounded within the foregoing range specified. It means, that my image is being distorted, when its size doesn't fit to the range in Excel.

If I take down the range, and confine it to the one cell, as in the code below:

```
Public Sub ResizeCab2()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim targetShpe As Shape
    
    ' Define the sheet that has the pictures
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Define the range the images is going to fit
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("B3")
    
    ' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
    For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes

        ' Check "picture" word in name
        If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
            ' Call the resize function
            SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
        End If

    Next targetShape
    
End Sub
```

Then I get the image in this cell only

[image]

This is the function, which comes with these two codes:

```
Private Sub SizeToRange(ByVal targetShape As Shape, ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Adjust picture properties
    With targetShape
        ' Check if next line is required...
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Left = Target.Left + 10
        .Top = Target.Top - 4
        .Width = Target.Width - 20
        .Height = Target.Height
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With

    ' Adjust picture border properties
    With targetShape.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

I also did the smallish changes in this function, replacing the:

```
        .Left = Target.Left + 10
        .Top = Target.Top - 4
```

with

```
         .Top = Range("B3").Top
        .Left = Range("B3").Left
```

but there is no effect, even with the `.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`.

I don't need these images distorted. I would like them stuck to the one (i.e. top left) corner expressed by one cell.

Comment: Hi there, not sure but it could you try to modify only the Height property ?   
(I mean removing that .Width = Target.Width - 20). It hard to keep a ratio and set both Height and Width. Let me know :)

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good hint from you. I switched off the Target.Width and Target.Height and now it works good I guess. Thank you.